# How to fix the following error message?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I want to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. I have Windows 10 loaded and I have also made a bootable DVD using Rufus.

But when I select the option "Boot from USB" in the BIOS setup, the Ubuntu starts loading and then I get the following messages:

```
[7.727945] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request for resource [mem0xce1730000-0xce87ggg]
(initramfs) mount :mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: No such device
Cannot mount /dev/loop0
```

and then it stops.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you verify the ISO after downloading?

Comment: @Kulfy, no How to do it

Comment: Calculate the MD5 sum of the ISO using CertUtil as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/898377/1049284) and check if it matches with the MD5 listed [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/MD5SUMS)